# Remove buttons from Panel

Tags: vscode-extensions, visual-studio-code

Is it possible to remove or customize the Panel (PROBLEMS, OUTPUT, DEBUG CONSOLE and TERMINAL buttons/bar)? I think the bezel is too big.

[image: console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tab UI elements mentioned are baked into the current VS Code aesthetic and interface, and cannot be disabled.

*If you wish to see a feature added allowing the disable of the tabs, please start an issue on the [VS Code GitHub Issues page](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues).*

Comment: Thanks ifconfig! I have put in a feature request https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/34349, feel free to upvote if you find it useful :)